# Why can't my object access protected members of another object defined in common base class?

Tags: c++

The following code produces a compiler error:

> 'BaseTest::_protMember' : cannot access protected member declared in
>   class 'BaseTest'

Why can't I access the member variable `_protMember` in my `class SubTest` even though it is protected?

```
class BaseTest
{
public:
    BaseTest(){};

    BaseTest(int prot)
    {
        _protMember = prot;
    };

protected:
    int _protMember;
};

class SubTest : public BaseTest
{
    // followup question
    SubTest(const SubTest &subTest)
    {
        _protMember = subTest._protMember; // this line compiles without error
    };

    SubTest(const BaseTest &baseTest)
    {
        _protMember = baseTest._protMember; // this line produces the error
    };
};
```

---

**Followup question:**

Why is it, that in the added copy constructor **I can access protected members** of another instance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only access `protected` members from your own base class instance... not one provided to you as a parameter.  It's all about OO encapsulation really.  Without this restriction, the object under construction could invalidate invariants of the `baseTest&` parameter.

Put another way, your `SubTest` may decide on a use for a `protected` member that conflicts with the usage made of the same member by another `BaseTest`-derived class (say `SubTest2 : BaseTest`).  If your `SubTest` code was allowed to fiddle with the other object's data, it could invalidate the invariants in a `SubTest2` object, or get some values out that were - in the intended encapsulation - only meant to be exposed to `SubTest2` and (optionally - see below) `SubTest2` derivatives.

> Followup question:
>   Why is it, that in the added copy constructor I can access protected members of another instance?

```
SubTest(const SubTest& x);  // can access x._protMember
SubTest(const BaseTest& x);  // cannot access x._protMember
```

The same insights above explain why this is allowed: the copy constructor gets a `SubTest&` rather than just any old object derived from `BaseTest`, and this constructor is clearly within the `SubTest` abstraction. The `SubTest` coder is assumed to be conversant with the intended design/encapsulation `SubTest` provides, and the copy constructor is given access to bypass and enforce post-conditions/invariants on the other `SubTest&` object too.  (You are copying from an object that might itself have been copy-constructed by the very same function, so protecting it when on the "`*this`" side but not the parameter-by-ref side isn't much protection at all, even ignoring all the sound reasons you may want/need that access).

It is possible that a `SubTest`-derived object will be accidentally passed to the `SubTest` copy constructor ("slicing"), but even for that scenario the `SubTest&` class can control whether the further-derived object could have been doing anything unexpected with `_protMember` - adding a `private` `using BaseTest::_protMember;` statement if it wants to "finalise" access to `_protMember` and forbid any derived classes from using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you have a look at my followup question I added (with a function that _can_ access protected members of another instance.

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: I've added to my answer addressing that. ("that can access protected members of another instance" - but not a `BaseTest`-but-not-`SubTest`-derived instance - there's the rub).

Comment: This is a great answer. I came across this issue a few years ago and it took me a long time to work out **why** the compiler behaved that way. What I realized is that the designers of C++ have done a great job in understanding the subtleties of where the responsibilities lie in object orientation.

Answer (score 6):

You can access `protected` members only in the class instance. That is :

```
class SubTest : public BaseTest
{
    SubTest(const BaseTest &baseTest)
    {
        _protMember = baseTest._protMember;
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^ Is good because you are in the instance of its class
        _protMember = baseTest._protMember;
     //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Produce error because you are not in the baseTest instance.              
    };

    // followup question
    SubTest(const SubTest &subTest)
    {
        _protMember = subTest._protMember;
      // Compile because access modifiers work on class level, and not on object level.
    };
};
```

**EDIT for the followup :**

> The access modifiers work on class level, and not on object level.
>
> That is, two objects of the same class can access each others private members.

This is my source : [Why can I access private variables in the copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117002/why-can-i-access-private-variables-in-the-copy-constructor)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you have a look at the followup in my edited question?

Comment: See 5th line of your code - wasn't it supposed to be ``subTest._protMember`` ?

Comment: @Shumail92 Actually no, when I posted it the first time, the test was just with baseTest :) I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

By defining `_protMember` as `protected` you allow objects of derived classes to access **their own** `_protMember`. This does not mean all objects of derived classes can access `_protMember` of other objects.