# Cannot access protected member of another instance from derived type's scope

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, encapsulation, protected

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17717142/5470596) to the question "*Why can't my object access protected members of another object defined in common base class?*", one can read:

> You can only access protected members from your own base class instance.

Either I don't get it correctly or the [following MCVE (live on coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0550246b42210ca) proves it wrong:

```
struct Base           { void f(); protected: int prot; };
struct Derived : Base { void g(); private:   int priv; };

void Base::f()
{
    Base b;
    b.prot = prot;
    (void) b;
}

void Derived::g()
{
    {
        Derived d;
        (void) d.priv;
    }

    {
        Derived& d = *this;
        (void) d.priv;
    }

    {
        Derived d;
        (void) d.prot; // <-- access to other instance's protected member
    }

    {
        Derived& d = *this;
        (void) d.prot;
    }

    // ---

    {
        Base b;
        (void) b.prot; // error: 'int Base::prot' is protected within this context
    }

    {
        Base& b = *this;
        (void) b.prot; // error: 'int Base::prot' is protected within this context
    }
}
```

In the light of the two errors I get to wonder: why can I access to another `Derived` instance's protected member from the scope of `Derived` but cannot access to another `Base` instance's protected member from the same scope regardless of the fact that `Derived` devires from `Base`? Tl; dr: what makes `protected` more "private" than `private` in this case?

*Notes*:

- please don't close this question as a duplicate of the linked question;
- better title suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Access specifiers work the same even if you *see the object* in scope. You use a `Base` reference, and that's all she wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule in [[class.access.base]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.base#5) is:

> A member `m` is accessible at the point *R* when named in class `N` if [...]
>
> - `m` as a member of `N` is protected, and *R* occurs in a member or friend of class `N`, or in a member of a class `P` derived from `N`, where `m` as a member of `P` is `public`, `private`, or `protected`

There's a lot of letters in there. But there are basically two conditions:

1. `R` is in a member or friend of the class. This handles the `d.prot` example - we are in a member of `Derived` while accessing a protected member of `Derived`.
2. `R` is in a member of a derived class and the member being accessed *is a member of* the derived class instance. This handles the `b.prot` example - we are in a member of a derived class, but `prot` is not a member of the derived class.

In other words, `Derived` can access `Base`'s protected members - but only in the case that it is accessing its own subobject's protected members. It cannot access other `Base` object's protected members. This makes sense when you consider that this other `Base` could easily be `SomeOtherDerived`, in which case that's just another unrelated object to us that we have no special access privileges to.

Comment: This answer confirms `protected` access specifier is not as simple as `private` and `public` are!