# Bypassing protected with inheritance and function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I've seen the following pattern used a couple of times to access protected member functions.

```
class A{
public:
    virtual ~A(){};
protected:
        void foo(){}
};

class B : public A{};


class Hacky : public B{
public:
    using B::foo;
};

int main(){
    B b;
    A& a = b;
    auto ptr = &Hacky::foo;
    (a.*ptr)();
}
```

I argue that this is undefined behavior following [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access), Built-in pointer-to-member access operators, point 5 (here E1 dynamic type is B and it doesn't contain Hacky::foo), but I'm not 100% sure. Could some give a definitive answer on that ?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550663/access-to-protected-member-through-member-pointer-is-it-a-hack is for fields but the reasoning should be same,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [type of `ptr`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be3c50e8638b489d) is `void (A::*)()`, not `void (Hacky::*)()`, so it is fine.